# Prevent Entity Framework from casting

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a query doing a grouping like this :

```
from order in orders group by 
   new { CustomerID = order.CustomerID, 
         Year = order.OrderDate.Year, 
         Month = order.OrderDate.Month } into g 
   select new {
      Total = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.UnitPrice }
```

I get an error:

> Arithmetic overflow

I looked into the SQL generated and it is trying to cast `Quantity` from int to decimal as the `UnitPrice` is decimal. In SQL the query works fine if I don't do the casting.

How can I enforce EF to not do casting of `Quantity` to decimal so it does not throw exception?

Comment: What about casting UnitPrice to a double in C#? (accepting rounding errors).

Comment: What is the quantity and price that is giving an overflow?  I suspect something else is wrong like a value being null.

Comment: It worked @user2864740, i have been fiddling around this for a while, casting it to double in c# made the sql generate cast both quantity and commission to "as float" finally

Comment: @Ahmed If it has worked and you have found the solution then post here as an answer. It would help for others.

Comment: I thank @user2864740 for giving the answer but since he put it as comment i can't mark it as answered so i will post the answer

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer if someone got the same Arithmetic overflow cast exception. The key is to cast the `decimal` value to `double` so the generated SQL will cast both to float (weird but worked).

The reason this is happening because the sql is dedcuted from c# expression tree, multiplying decimal and integer translates to upcasting the int to decimal in c# since the * takes 2 parameters of same type, which explains the resulted sql trying to cast the Quantity to decimal, to solve this issue manual casting is needed, hope this helps someone else facing same issue :

```
from order in orders group by 
    new { CustomerID= order.CustomerID, 
    Year= order.OrderDate.Year, 
    Month= order.OrderDate.Month } into g 
    select new {
        Total= g.Sum(x=>x.Quanitty * (double)x.UnitPrice
        }
```